# If else statement doesn't work in C

Tags: c, if-statement, codeblocks

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    //Declaration
    char grade[1];

    //Data Input
    enter code here
    printf("Enter a grade{A,B,C,D,F]: ");
    scanf("%c",&grade);

    //If Statement

    if(grade=='a'=='A')
        printf("The score for the grade 'A' is 4.00");
    else
        if(grade=='b '=='B')
            printf("The score for the grade 'B' is 3.00");
        else
            if(grade=='c'=='C')
                printf("The score for the grade 'C' is 2.00");
            else
                if(grade=='d'=='D')
                    printf("The score for the grade 'D' is 1.00");
```

I try it so many times but the if else statement just didn't pop up
I trying to make the program recognize both upper case and lower case of the grade A-F or a-f. but it didn't seem to work

Enter a grade{A,B,C,D,F]: a

Process returned 1 (0x1)   execution time : 2.599 s
Press any key to continue.

gives me this

Comment: You are comparing the result of an equivalence check to a character? Why?

Comment: What is `grade=='a'=='A'` supposed to do, exactly? Because I guarantee it doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't fail.  Your comparison fails.  You are saying:

```
If (grade is equal to 'a') is equal to'A'....
```

Which can never be true.  Try:

```
if(grade == 'a' || grade == 'A')...
```

Comment: I think you mean "If grade is equal to 'a' is itself equal to 'A'".

Comment: No. It will be evaluated as `if grade is equal to 'a'` which will result in `true` for his sample input `a`, then it will compare `if true is equal to 'A'`.

Comment: I rarely understand why a correct, accepted answer gets down voted.

Answer (score 3):

Look closely at:

```
if(grade=='a'=='A')
```

Operators of the same type go from left to right, so this is the same as

```
if ((grade == 'a') == 'A')
```

So you are comparing the results of comparing `grade` to `'a'` to `'A'`. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is to make the program recognize a and also A if the user enters either one of those. but what you said i tried it but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @johnk I don't understand what you are saying. What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(grade=='a'=='A')
```

doesn't do what you want -- it evaluates `grade == 'a'`, which is either true (1) or false (0), and then compares *that* value against `'A'`, which will *never* be true<sup>1</sup>.

You would normally handle multiple comparisons like this:

```
if ( grade == 'a' || grade == 'A' ) // grade equals 'a' OR grade equals 'A'
```

However, the *right* way to handle case-insenstitive comparison is to use one of the `toupper` or `tolower` library functions to convert everything to either upper or lower case:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
if ( tolower( grade ) == 'a' )
```

If `grade` is entered as `'A'`, the result of `tolower( grade )` will be `'a'`.  If `grade` is entered as `'a'`, the result of `tolower( grade )` will be `'a'`.  This way you only have to compare against the single value.

Also, you might want to consider using the `switch` control structure as opposed to a chain of `if-else` statements:

```
switch( tolower( grade ) )
{
  case 'a' : printf( "Score for grade A is 4.00\n" ); break;
  case 'b' : printf( "Score for grade B is 3.00\n" ); break;
  case 'c' : printf( "Score for grade C is 2.00\n" ); break;
  case 'd' : printf( "Score for grade D is 1.00\n" ); break;
  case 'f' : break;
  default  : printf( "%c is not a valid grade\n", grade ); break;
}
```

This way you're only evaluating `tolower( grade )` once and your code doesn't march across the page.

Other random nits...

1. `main` returns `int`, not `void`.  Your compiler may or may not complain about it, but you should not use `void main()`.  Use `int main( void )` if your program doesn't take any command-line arguments, `int main( int argc, char **argv)` if it does.
2. Be careful when writing out your character constants - `'b '` is not the same as `'b'`, and may not be processed the way you expect.
3. Be careful when using the `%c` conversion specifier with `scanf`.  Unlike the `%s` and `%d` and `%f` conversion specifiers, it will not skip over any leading whitespace.  This is especially dangerous when doing interactive input, since it will pick up the trailing newline from the previous input.  To make sure you skip over leading whitespace, put a blank space in the format string in front of the specifier: `scanf( " %c", &grade );`.
4. Check the result of `scanf` to make sure you actually read something before trying to process it.  `scanf` will return the number of successful conversions and assignments (0 if the input doesn't match the conversion specifier) or `EOF` if there was an input error.

---

1. Well, unless you find a system that encodes `'A'` as 1, which you won't, and even if you do, that means all the remaining tests will still fail for the same reason.